Kinesis data stream - TRIM_HORIZON not showing recently added data
I am using boto3 to put data in Kinesis data stream. The code is running successfully and returns response with 200 status. But when I check the data in AWS console, am not able to see the recently added data with TRIM_HORIZON configuration.

Only if I specify the Starting position as At sequence number, I am able to see this data.

My question is, TRIM_HORIZON shows all the data from the start. Then why is it not showing the newly added data?

I had something similar recently where the console did not show many records, but accessing data via the API showed thousands of records. Not sure if that has always been the behaviour.

Yeah it works through API. I believe it's because of how TRIM_HORIZON works. It fetches a shard iterator starting from the oldest available record. If that shard iterator has no data, it can't show any records. However, when I use the boto3 get_records function, I eventually see data after passing through many empty shard iterators. I believe the console also has this issue, and if I keep clicking on "Get records," I might see data eventually, but I'm not entirely sure.
